# SQL QUERY returning all results using OR in WHERE statement

Tags: php, mysql

Hoping I am just missing something simple here:

```
    $sql = "Select * FROM user_info, user_login WHERE user_login.status = '0' OR user_login.status = '2' AND user_info.uid = user_login.uid";

$db = new connection();
                $results = $db->query($sql);

$user = array();    

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($results))

{

$user[] = $info;

}

$total = count($user);
//TEST the amount of rows returned.
echo $total;

for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++)
{

//echo data;
}
```

just trying to pull all data that has the user_login.status field set to "0" or "2"  but it shows everything thing and it shows the items marked as 2 twice.
 Does anyone see my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Select * FROM user_info, user_login WHERE (user_login.status = '0' OR user_login.status = '2') AND user_info.uid = user_login.uid

Order of precedence :)

Answer (score 8):

Your precedence is getting whacked because of missing parentheses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM user_info, user_login
WHERE (user_login.status = '0' OR user_login.status = '2')
AND user_info.uid = user_login.uid
```

Without seeing the data I can't give you more than a `SELECT DISTINCT` with regards to the duplicate records.